# Is there a possibility to get guildsize from a bot, other than mine?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Is there a possibility to get guildsize from a bot, other than mine? Like that:

[image: Screenshot]

I found in discord api a GET / users / @ me / guilds, which allows me to get the total guilds I'm in, but I can't find a way to get someone's guildsize.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. The way that website has the bots server count is that the bots directly communicate their server count to the site through an API.
I'm not sure which website is that but [here's the API page for top.gg](https://top.gg/api/docs#bots), the endpoint used for communicated is "Post Bot Stats".

Comment: HM,I see but 
but then the code could easily be modified

Comment: If the bot is on top.gg you *can* get that information. Should say "not possible unless..."

Comment: @StrikeEagle I believe the top.gg API only allows you to retrieve stats from your own bots, but I'm not sure about that

Comment: Could also just use Puppeteer to scrape the data directly if the API dosnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the guild size like so

```
<Client>.guilds.size
```

Here is the link of the discordjs [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds)